# Why do we pass greater<string>() to the sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

As I know, Functor is basically a class that overrides `operator ()`. Now I will have to first instantiate a class, to use the override operator. For example -

```
class A {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a<b;
    }
}
```

Now when I want to pass this to sort function, I will first have to instantiate it.

```
A instance;
sort(a.begin(),a.end(),instance);
```

The above should be correct implementation as I am passing a function to sort function which it can use for comparison. Why do I have to pass `instance()` as argument instead of instance.

One more thing: when I pass something like greater(), I am not even instantiating the class!

Comment: You don't. Your code is correct, you simply need to make `operator()` public in `A`. When you do `sort(a.begin(), a.end(), greater())` you are constructing an instance of `greater`.

Comment: @Holt: Answers in the answer section please mate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::greater` is a functional object that is it is a structure that provides the function call operator.

Expression

```
std::greater<std::string>()
```

calls the constructor of the structure and creates a temporary object of type `std::greater<std::string>` for which the function call operator can be called in an algorithm.

Relative to your function object definition

```
class A {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const {
        return a<b;
    }
}
```

to create an instance of the class you should use expression

```
A()
```

So you can write either

```
std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), A() );
```

or

```
A instance;
std::sort( a.begin(), a.end(), instance );
```

Take into account that the results are equivalent for these code snippets

```
std::cout << A()( 10, 20 ) << std::endl;
```

and

```
A instance;

std::cout << instance( 10, 20 ) << std::endl;
```

Comment: So basically , when I do something like this - [](int a,int b) { return a<b; }, it automatically creates a class with () operator overriden and instantiates it for me. And why I don't have to mention a return type in the above code.

Comment: @ShubhamJain Yes lambda expressions are classes with the function call operator that corresponds to the body of lambda expression.

Comment: @ShubhamJain As can be seen at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda lambda expressions doesn't need to specify return type if they contain nothing but a single return statement. (Always(?) legal since c++14 (deduced in the same way as auto))

Answer (score 3):

> Why do I have to pass instance() as argument instead of instance.

You don't.

Either pass `instance` (the name of the instance), or `A()` (which is a separate, temporary, instance).

> One more thing , when I pass something like greater(), I am not even instantiating the class !

Sure you are. This is a temporary of type `greater`.

---

Don't forget to make your `operator()` be `public`.